# Refactoring Ruby If/Else with iteration and pushing into array

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to clean up a method that iterates over data that is being pushed into arrays. It's something like:

```
def sort_by_title(authors)
 general = []
 fiction = []
 factual = []
 food = []
 other = []

 authors.each do |a|
  if a.tag.include?('General')
   general << a
  elsif a.tag.include?('Historical')
    fiction << a if a.tag.include?('iction')
    factual <<a if a.tag.include?('actual')
  elseif a.tag.include?('Food')
    food << a
  else
    other << a
  end
 end
 (general + fiction + factual + food + other).flatten
end
end
```

Rubocop is hitting me with: `Metrics/AbcSize and Metrix/Perceived Complexity`. Is there a cleaner way I can do this?

Comment: Is `tag` a string or an array? (e.g. can each other have more than one tag?)

Comment: Cleaner way to do what? Please provide a description of what the code is supposed to accomplish or an example of input and output.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with `case`:

```
authors.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }) do |a, hash|
  case a.tag
  when /General/ then h[:general] << a
  when /Historical.*iction/ then h[:fiction] << a
  when /Historical.*actual/ then h[:factual] << a
  when /Food/ then h[:food] << a
  else h[:other] << a
end.values.flatten
```

Or, more exciting and semantically correct approach with [`Enumerable#sort_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by):

```
authors.sort_by do |a|
  [
    10 if a.tag.include?('General'),
    if a.tag.include?('iction')
      8
    elsif if a.tag.include?('actual')
      6
    end if a.tag.include?('Historical'),
    4 if a.tag.include?('Food'),
    2
  ].compact.sum
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`#group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):

```
def sort_by_title(authors)
  grouped = authors.group_by do |a| 
    if a.tag.include?('General')
      :general
    elsif a.tag.include?('Historical')
      :fiction if a.tag.include?('iction')
      :factual if a.tag.include?('actual')
    elsif a.tag.include?('Food')
      :food
    else
      :other
    end
  end
  grouped.values.flatten
end
```

EDIT:

To make it cleaner, you can extract method deciding about genre:

```
class Author
  def genre
    if tag.include?('General')
      :general
    elsif tag.include?('Historical')
      :fiction if tag.include?('iction')
      :factual if tag.include?('actual')
    elsif tag.include?('Food')
      :food
    else
      :other
    end
  end
end

def sort_by_title(authors)
  authors.group_by(&:genre).values.flatten
end
```

Comment: Really like it as it's cleaner but it's still hitting Perceived complexity for sort_by_title is too high

Answer (score 0):

Do you need them grouped, or sorted? If it's just sorted can you use [sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) with a lookup field?

```
TAGS = {
  'General' => 1,
  'Fiction' => 2,
  'Factual' => 3,
  'Food' => 4,
  'Other' => 5
}

authors = [
  { name: 'Joe', tag: 'General' },
  { name: 'Sue', tag: 'Fiction' },
  { name: 'Sally', tag: 'Food' },
  { name: 'Oliver', tag: 'Factual' },
  { name: 'Bob', tag: 'Other' },
  { name: 'Billy', tag: 'General' }
]

sorted_authors =
  authors.sort_by do |author|
    TAGS[author[:tag]] # This would be author.tag in your example
  end

puts sorted_authors
```

Yields

```
{:name=>"Joe", :tag=>"General"}
{:name=>"Billy", :tag=>"General"}
{:name=>"Sue", :tag=>"Fiction"}
{:name=>"Oliver", :tag=>"Factual"}
{:name=>"Sally", :tag=>"Food"}
{:name=>"Bob", :tag=>"Other"}
```